# How do I trigger a callback from a keyboard press? Includes example with error

Tags: python, callback

I'm working on a raspberry pi project and I'd like to be able to set a button press, specifically '0', to respond with zeroing out a number. I have a callback set using the signal library to break a loop and end the program with SIGINT, but I can't figure out a way to capture specific keyboard presses without using a while loop. I tried the below, which I saw somewhere else on this site, on my windows laptop (not yet on the Pi), but I get a Type Error.

```
import keyboard
import time


num_val = 10


def here():
    global num_val
    num_val = 0
    print('Keyboard Press Triggered')


keyboard.on_press_key('f', here)

while num_val is not 0:
    time.sleep(0.5)

print('End')
```

I get this error when I press 'f'

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Somestuff\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Somestuff\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Somestuff\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 58, in process
    if self.pre_process_event(event):
  File "C:\Somestuff\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 213, in pre_process_event
    key_hook(event)
  File "C:\Somestuff\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 510, in <lambda>
    return hook_key(key, lambda e: e.event_type == KEY_UP or callback(e), suppress=suppress)
TypeError: here() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What is wrong with the above program? Why is 'here' taking an argument? Is there a better way to trigger a function on keyboard press using callbacks? I don't want to make a while loop specifically for monitoring a button press since I already have a while loop where I am performing some actions in my Pi program. I'd much rather have a callback that just changes a value when '0' is pressed. Is there a way I could pass my num_val to the function instead of using 'global num_val'?

Comment: if you cast `keyboard.on_press_key('f', here())` does it still raise the exception? Your `here` method is currently receiving the key press `f` as an input to the method. You could also try declaring the key in your method declaration `def here(key_pressed):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.hook)

> The event passed to the callback is of type keyboard.KeyboardEvent, with the following
>
> name: an Unicode representation of the character (e.g. "&") or description (e.g. "space"). The name is always lower-case.
>
> scan_code: number representing the physical key, e.g. 55.
>
> time: timestamp of the time the event occurred, with as much precision as given by the OS.

Basically, the callback sends more data about the event to your function. If you don't care about that data, you can just accept it in the function definition but not do anything with it, i.e.:

```py
def here(event = None):
    global num_val
    num_val = 0
    print('Keyboard Press Triggered')
```

Comment: This worked, thanks for the response. I'll read a bit more into the documentation. I'm still very new to programming and don't even know exactly what I'm reading. Even reading the bit that you linked I don't really understand it. If I wanted to utilize some of that information, such as the time the even occurred, how would I add that?

Comment: @ElectraTech not a problem, welcome to the programming world! I have not used that package per se, but I believe you could do something like `print('Time: {}'.format(event.time))`

Comment: This also worked. I understand it a bit more too. So it looks like I can just follow the same formula and do `print('Name: {}'.format(event.name))` to print out the character received as well. Much appreciated

Comment: @ElectraTech yup, as long as something has a way of being displayed as a `string`, you can `print()` it out.